# How do I implement a NN with BFGS optimizer

Tags: python, numpy

Here is what I tried:

```
def loss(W):
    weightsList1 = [np.zeros((25,20)), np.zeros(20)]
    for i in range(20):
        for j in range(25):
            weightsList1[0][j,i] = W[i][j]
        weightsList1[1][i] = W[i][25]

    model.layers[0].set_weights(weightsList1)
    weightsList2 = [np.zeros((20,1)), np.zeros(1)]

    for i in range(20):
        weightsList2[0][i,0] = W[0][i]

    weightsList2[1][0] = W[0][20]
    model.layers[1].set_weights(weightsList2)
    preds = model.predict(X)
    mse = np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(preds,Y)))/len(X[:,0])

    return mse


V = np.random.randn(20,26)*0.01
res = minimize(loss, x0=V, method = 'BFGS', options={'eps': 1e-6,'disp': True})
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: Hi Anukruti! Could you please be more elaborate with your question? possibly share a sample row of your train dataset.

Comment: Why isn't your function indented?

Comment: @tsumit . Here is the first row of my data-  133833.0 33509.0, 48622.0 133833.0 0.0, 20808.0, 6769.0, 6769.0, 94358.0, 163143.0 ... 38090.0, -4039.0, 20813.0, 27432.0, 27432.0, 19.771458, 12832.027652, 192862.0, 0.557271, 6.931479. It has 25 input values and I applied a sequential model to build a single hidden layer NN